# How to make this kind of dialog in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I tried this but, i do't get my actual output.
I am trying many solution but not getting proper.
share your answeer for this solution.

```
card:{
 height:150,
 width:"80%",
 backgroundColor:"white",
 borderRadius:15,
 padding:10,
 elevation:10,
 shadowColor: '#000',
 shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 3 },
 shadowOpacity: 0.5,
 shadowRadius: 5, 
}
```

[image: a]

Answer (score 0):

It's not about `react-native` but css.
you should create a `View` element and position it under the dialogue modal with such style:

`arrowDown {
  width: 0,
  height: 0, 
  borderLeftColor: transparent,
  borderRightColor: transparent,
  borderTopWidth: 20,
  borderRightWidth: 20,
  borderLeftWidth: 20,
  borderTopColor: #f00,
}`

for reference, you can check out this tutorial on how to create a triangle in CSS: [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/#:~:text=The%20idea%20is%20a%20box,transparent%2C%20which%20forms%20the%20triangle.)

Comment: thanks for sharing, this also i tried before post but not getting my actual reasult

Comment: I'm sure you're doing something wrong because this is something I've done before in a react-native project.